# Using kafka streams to create a table based on elasticsearch events

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is it possible to use Kafka streaming to create a pipeline that reads JSON from a Kafka topic and then do some logic with them and send the results to another Kafka topic or something else?

For example, I populate my topic using logs from elasticsearch. That is pretty easy using a simple logstash pipeline.

Once I have my logs in the kafka topic, I want to extract some pieces of information from the log and put them in a sort of "table" with N column(is Kafka capable of this?) and then put the table somewhere else (another topic or a db).

I didn't find any example that satisfies my criteria.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

There is no concept of columns in kafka or kafka-streams. However, you typically just define a plain old java object of your choice, with the fields that your want (fields being the equivalent of columns in this case). You produce the output in that format to an output topic (using an appropriately chosen serializer). Finally, if you want to store the result in a relational database, you map the fields into columns, typically using a kafka connect jdbc sink:
http://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html

Comment: Would you please post and example of what you said? thank you

Comment: There are many examples and demo apps available under https://github.com/confluentinc/examples.  This might be a good starting point for you @ennon.